# Metadata file 'Domain.dll' could not be found when using CSharpCodeProvider referencing project

Tags: c#

I have a solution with two assemblies, one of these is called Domain and contains a Book class and an Author class.

I want to dynamically create a class which inherits from the Book class.  Here's my code:

```
public Book CreateBookProxy(Book book)
    {
      CSharpCodeProvider cscp = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<String, String> { { "CompilerVersion", "v3.5" } });
      var parameters = new CompilerParameters(new[] { "mscorlib.dll", "System.Core.dll", "Domain.dll" }, "Proxies.dll", false);
      parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;

      var compileUnit = new CodeCompileUnit();
      var ns = new CodeNamespace("Proxies");
      compileUnit.Namespaces.Add(ns);
      ns.Imports.Add(new CodeNamespaceImport("System"));
      ns.Imports.Add(new CodeNamespaceImport("Domain"));

      var classType = new CodeTypeDeclaration("BookProxy");
      classType.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public;
      classType.BaseTypes.Add(new CodeTypeReference(typeof(Book)));
      ns.Types.Add(classType);
      var results = cscp.CompileAssemblyFromDom(parameters, compileUnit);

      List<string> errors = new List<string>();
      errors.AddRange(results.Errors.Cast<CompilerError>().Select(e => e.ErrorText));

      return Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("Proxies.BookProxy, Proxies")) as Book;
    }
```

However I'm getting the following error:

> Metadata file 'Domain.dll' could not be found

Domain.dll is referenced in my start up project so it exists in the bin folder at run time.

Interestingly Assembly.Load("Domain.dll"); throws a FileNotFoundException

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: It's part of the solution, and it exists in the bin folder at runtime

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would suggest explicitly specify the location of `Domain.dll` as following:

```
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(typeof(<TYPE FROM DOMAIN.DLL>).Assembly.Location);
```

Comment: What if you do not yet know the type you want to load?

Comment: @WilkovanderVeen Then you'll have to know the full path to assembly or directory with assembly should be specified in [probing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w.aspx) element in config file.